# IPAddress from NSData using Bonjour NSNetService in MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, bonjour, nsnetservice

I'm using Xamarin + MonoTouch on iOS to browse for a web server on the network that I can then download files from.

The NSNetService that is passed into the resolve event handler contains addresses as NSData. I can't find a good way to turn that NSData into an actual IP address that I can then build a URL from, i.e. http:// < IPAddress > /folder/file.htm

This is my NSNetService.AddressResolved event handler:

```
private void OnServiceResolved(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
        NSNetService service = (NSNetService)sender;
        // service.Port is valid.
        // service.HostName is valid.
        // but we want the IP addres, which is in service.Addresses.
        // None of the following four methods works quite right.
        IPAddress address = (IPAddress)service.Addresses [0]; // Cannot convert type NSData to IPAddress
        SocketAddress address2 = (SocketAddress)service.Addresses[0]; // Cannot convert NSData to SocketAddress. A binary copy might work?
        IPHostEntry entry = (IPHostEntry)service.Addresses [0]; // Cannot convert NSData to IPHostEntry
        IPHostEntry entry2 = Dns.GetHostByName (service.HostName); // This kinda works, but is dumb. Didn't we just resolve?
}
```

What's the right way to get the IP address of the service from an NSNetService in a resolve event?

Comment: Code snippet for parsing NSData which supports IPv6 and IPv4: https://gist.github.com/jbe2277/4b9f5ac0fb3556569960d2e1f3c5bf28

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NSNetService.Addresses` property gives you `NSData` instances which must be converted into something that `IPAddress` (or other .NET types) can digest. E.g.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream ();
(ns.Addresses [0] as NSData).AsStream ().CopyTo (ms);
IPAddress ip = new IPAddress (ms.ToArray ());
```

Note that this can return you an IPv6 address (or format that `IPAddress` won't accept). You might want to iterate all the `Addresses` to find the *best* one.

I'll look into adding a convenience method into future versions of Xamarin.iOS.

**UPDATE**

A more complete version, that returns an `IPAddress`, would look like:

```
static IPAddress CreateFrom (NSData data)
{
    byte[] address = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream ()) {
        data.AsStream ().CopyTo (ms);
        address = ms.ToArray ();
    }
    SocketAddress sa = new SocketAddress (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, address.Length);
    // do not overwrite the AddressFamily we provided
    for (int i = 2; i < address.Length; i++)
        sa [i] = address [i];
    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint (IPAddress.Any, 0);
    return (ep.Create (sa) as IPEndPoint).Address;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It would be wonderful to have an easy conversion in Xamarin. :)